# Using Concatenated Vlookup in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, vlookup

I can't seem to figure out how to concatenate two cell inputs (myvalue = Cell D2 and myvalue2 = Cell C3; the cells can change hence the input function) in to an application.vlookup vba.

Online it says you can't use the concatenate function with application.worksheetfunction.vlookup so trying to figure out an alternative. Any thoughts?

```
Dim myValue As String
Dim myValue2 As String

myValue = InputBox("Please input Cell that first merch cat is in")
myValue2 = InputBox("Please input Cell that first site is in")
    
ActiveCell = Application.VLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False)
```

[image]

Comment: Not so clear what you try accomplishing... If you have two strings "dog" and "cat" and you want using `Vlookup` to search for a cell containing "dogcat" and returning according to this match, it is working. But you should simple use `Vlookup(myValue2 & myValue, `. No need of any evaluation. If you want something else, please better explain **what you want accomplishing**. With examples, please. Do you want searching for each variable in different columns, or what?

Comment: The value of cell D3 = 11502
The value of cell C2 = 930

I want it to concatenate them both to use as a vlookup but instead I 'think' it is just bringing back the actual string of 'C3D2'

Comment: So, what? What does explain that? Where do you use "D3" in your code? Did you understand my clarification question from my first comment? Is it something not clear?

Comment: so the concatenation I'd like is '93011502' but instead it is bringing back 'C3D2'

Comment: What "is bringing back 'C3D2' " does mean? Where is it bringing back anything? Please, use a clear example. Something like: In cells x and y there are values xxx and yyy. I use the function in this way: `ActiveCell = Application.VLookup(.....` , wanting to return from "BA:BE"" zzzz, which is in column "BE" and in "BA" it searches for wwww. But it returns  qqqq...

Comment: Using the code below, it is not bringing back the value of the cell, it is bringing back the actual cell number I am inputting in to the input box.

So I want to find out what value is in cell C3 (Which is '930')
I also want to find out what value is in cell D2 (Which is '11502')

I then want to concatenate these two results together to use as a vlookup value.

Dim myValue As String
Dim myValue2 As String
    
    myValue = InputBox("Please input Cell that first merch cat is in")
    myValue2 = InputBox("Please input Cell that first site is in")

ActiveCell = myValue2 & myValue

Comment: Did you read my above comment? **What strings do you input and what string to be match is in "BA"?** Can't you build a full example, using your real variable and real strings to be searched for, respectively, returned?

Comment: Cell BA= 93011502, cell BB = 11502, Cell BC = Test, Cell BD = Test, Cell BE = B1

Comment: I do not care about cells BB, BC and BD... **What is the first parameter (the concatenated one) of the `Vlookup` function**? And how column "BA:BA" is formatted? Is **it formatted as string**, or as number (`General`)?

Comment: =VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($C3&D2),$BA:$BE,5,0) is the formula that works with the concatenation required.

Cell BA1 =BF1&BB1 (This concatenates as 93011502)

The strings I input are "D2" and "C3"

Comment: Do you understand English, no offence? **I asked about the used variables format**... Then, does your `Vlookup` function work or not? I will try an answer, you will maybe understand better what I meant.

Comment: Do you want to get the value from "cat" from one row and the value from "dog" from another row and then put the values after each other (merge) and do a vlookup on the merged value?

Comment: If we bring things back to basics:
Step 1) input a cell value in to an input box and it bring back the contents of said cell.
Step 2) input another cell value in to an input box and it bring back the contents of said cell.
Step 3) Join those 2 values together so I can use it in a vlookup

Comment: Then the answer is what FaneDuru posted `myValue2 & myValue`

Comment: Did you here about **formatting** in Excel, no offence?

Comment: Generally speaking, looking up concatenated values is bad practise. Maybe not so much with your data, but the moment you retrieve false positives you'd have wished you looked for a Boolean structure or two-fold lookup earlier.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the assistance. Went away and looked at it from another angle and now works exactly how I wanted it to:

```
Dim myValue As Range

Set myValue = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please input Cell that first merch cat is in", Type:=8)
Set myValue2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please input Cell that first site is in", Type:=8)

 ActiveCell = Application.VLookup([myValue2] & [myValue], ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

With this setup

[image: lookup value as text]

and this code

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim valone As String
    Dim valtwo As String
    
    valone = InputBox("Enter one")
    valtwo = InputBox("Enter two")
    
    ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLookup(valone & valtwo, ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False)
    
End Sub
```

If I type `470` in the first prompt and `11516` in the second prompt, I get `A1` in the active cell. Note the green triangles in BA. I entered those numbers with a leading apostrophe so they would be considered text and not numeric. With this next setup, there are no triangles because BA contains numbers.

[image: lookup value as numbers]

In that case, the code returns #N/A because it can't find the text "47011516" in the list of numbers.  You could change your code to convert the input box results to a number using the `Val()` function.

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim valone As String
    Dim valtwo As String
    
    valone = InputBox("Enter one")
    valtwo = InputBox("Enter two")
    
    ActiveCell.Value = Application.VLookup(Val(valone & valtwo), ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False)
    
End Sub
```

And that will work. Another option is to use `Find` instead of a function. I would write it like this

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim valone As String
    Dim valtwo As String
    Dim rFind As Range
    
    valone = InputBox("Enter one")
    valtwo = InputBox("Enter two")
    
    Set rFind = ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BA").Find(valone & valtwo, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.Value = rFind.Offset(0, 4).Value
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = "not found"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

That won't care if it's a number or text.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try understanding an important issue about `Vlookup`:

**`lookup_value` and first column of `table_array` must be identically formatted!** to avoid `#N/A`...

I mean, if the value in "BA:BA" **is a number** and formatted as `General`, you should supply a numeric value as `lookup_value`:

`ActiveCell = Application.VLookup(CDbl(myValue2 & myValue), ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False)`

If it is formatted as Text, it should work in this way:

`ActiveCell = Application.VLookup(CStr(myValue2 & myValue), ActiveSheet.Range("BA:BE"), 5, False)`

In this second case, converting to string of two concatenated strings is just in case. Theoretically, it is not necessary...

Comment: BA:BA is a number. The vlookup value is also a number. Neither codes work unfortunately

Comment: I've added an image in the original post of my excel worksheet. D3 is the activecell I would have highlighted before activating the VBA. The answer is meant to be 'B1'

Comment: vlookup only works if the column BA is sorted ascending.

Comment: @Samgrill  How "vlookup value is also a number", since you build it by concatenation of two strings? Only you, lie a human being see it as a number. VBA considers it a string.

Comment: @Samgrill Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk applications installed? I would like to see, if possible, what happens in your environment...

Comment: @Loveb This is not true... It returns the first occurrence.

Comment: I still don't see the point, why set active cell to "93011502" instead of using =BF1&BB1. I give up.

Comment: @Loveb What "BF1&BB1"? It should be the value in BE, of the matched row. It is better to give up, I agree...

Comment: The activecell will be using the vlookup (Which used the lookup value of "93011502" to pull back the answer in column BE. It's not setting the cell to 93011502..

Comment: Any thoughts on just how I can concatenate myvalue and myvalue2 cell values together?

Comment: @Samgrill I am asking again: Do you have `TeamViewer` of `AnyDesk` installed? If I will be able to connect to your computer I will show you how to use it... Otherwise, I cannot get you.

Comment: @Samgrill Are you sure that you concatenated the InputBoxes strings **in the correct order**?

Comment: @Samgrill Still alive? Did you make it working?

Comment: Hello, I haven't got teamviewer or anydesk unfortunately. The concatenated inbox strings were in the right order yes, just brings back #N/A as the answer